# Website works good in localhost but not in hosting server

Tags: php

My website works flawlessly in my XAMPP localhost, and I tried to upload it in free hosting server to test it but I encountered these errors and I dont know how to fix them, please help.

the session.php is for pages that only logged in users can see, if tried to go to e.g dashboard.php when not logged in, page will redirect to login.php

Error 1 :

> Notice: Undefined index: login_user in /public_html/session.php on line 6
>   Go back

Error 2 :

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at public_html/session.php:6) in public_html/session.php on line 15

And this is my session.php

```
<?php

session_start();

include('db.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user']; //THIS IS LINE 6
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($db,"select  username,mem_id  from  member  where  
username='$user_check'  ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$loggedin_session=$row['username'];
$loggedin_id=$row['mem_id'];

if(!isset($loggedin_session)  ||  $loggedin_session==NULL)
{
echo  "Go  back";
header("Location: login.php"); //THIS IS LINE 15
}

?>
```

And Error 3 :

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /public_html/dashboard.php on line 41

This is my dashboard.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql="SELECT  *  FROM  member  where  mem_id=$loggedin_id";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
?>
<?php
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //THIS IS LINE 41
?>
```

If you noticed the open bracket in line 41, there is php code at the bottom of my dashboard page :

```
<?php
//  close  while  loop
}
?>

<?php
//  close  connection;
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

I really dont know if this is necessary or not because Im just getting ideas from other public and open source php codes online.

Comment: Make the line - `$user_check=isset($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : '';`

Comment: in dashboard.php, make sure `$loggedin_id` has value, else the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Notice: Undefined index: login_user in /public_html/session.php on line 6 Go back
```

It means that in $_SESSION, 'login_user' is not defined. So depending of your logic you might want to do something like

```
$user_check = isset($_SESSION['login_user']) ? $_SESSION['login_user'] : '';
```

Second error should be fixed once the first one is fixed.

Third error : `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /public_html/dashboard.php on line 41`

It means that your query failed. Maybe because $loggedin_id is not set or for an other reason (check mysqli_error (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) You might want to fix it, and for good practice, you should check it before doing anything else.
Example :

```
if ($result) {
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error : 1**

Check if `session` is set or not for `login_user` and then assign it to variable.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))  // Check for session is set or not
{
    $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user']; //THIS IS LINE 6
}
```

**Error : 2**

Make sure you not written anything or any code before `<?php` in your `session.php`.

If there, please remove. Also there should not be any code as `comment` before `<?php`.

**Error : 3**

That query is failing and is returning **false**.

Put this after `mysqli_query()` to see what's going on.

```
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
    exit();
}
```

For more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

They aren't errors..they are notice and warnings!!!

I assume in you local xamp php_ini settings you may have error settings as:
`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING`

and in your free app hosting the setting might just be `error_reporting = E_ALL`.

So, just cross check php.ini files on both your local and remote machine set it to same, and then  debug your errors or warnings before you host it!